# Stop CSS grid contents from expanding to fill cell

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm programming a web application with collapsible sidebar inside a CSS grid. The CSS grid divides the whole UI into sections, and the sidebar panel is a sub-component of one of those sections.

The issue I am running into is that I want the side panel to automatically shrink to the minimum size of it's contents, which it does fine until it's added to a CSS grid cell, at which point it expands to fill the entire cell.

Here is a quick example of the issue:

```
<style>
    #myGrid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
            "g1 g2";
    }

    #panel{
        grid-area: g2;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #FFAAAA;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        min-width: minmax(0, 1fr);
    }

    #panelContents{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #collapseArrow{
        align-self: center;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
    }

    #block{
        grid-area: g1;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #AAAAFF;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="myGrid">
        <div id="block">
            Contents
        </div>
        <div id="panel">
            <div id="panelContents">
                <div id="collapseContents">
                    <div class="item">
                        Item1
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        Item2
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        Item3
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        Item4
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        Item5
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseArrow">&lt;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any idea how to solve this? I am trying to get the red panel to shrink to fit it's contents. I tried changing the min-width to 0, but that didn't seem to help.

EDIT: This is a more complex UI for an HTML5 game engine. The left grid cell is an asset browser, and the red panel is a simple properties panel for the right editor window (right grid cell), which I'm trying to display only on the left portion of the cell, so the rest of the right cell can be the editor window.

Comment: Try changing the width to ``min-content``. Anyway, this is the expected behavior as setting width to auto inside a grid column will automatically size the element to take up the entire column width.

Comment: I tried that and no change. You were referring to setting the width of the panel element correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use the other column to squeeze the panel down to its content width.

```css
#myGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto; /* 1fr consumes all free space on the row */
  grid-template-areas: "g1 g2";
}

#block {
  grid-area: g1;
  background: #AAAAFF;
}

#panel {
  grid-area: g2;
  background: #FFAAAA;
}

#panelContents {
  display: flex;
}

#collapseArrow {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myGrid">
  <div id="block">
    Contents
  </div>
  <div id="panel">
    <div id="panelContents">
      <div id="collapseContents">
        <div class="item">Item1</div>
        <div class="item">Item2</div>
        <div class="item">Item3</div>
        <div class="item">Item4</div>
        <div class="item">Item5</div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseArrow">&lt;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The plan is to have it a side panel, meaning there will be content in the rest of the cell, so using another column to squish it doesn't seem like a good solution to that.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Updated the original post to add more detail